# n-th child selector not working in react map render function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I have a react component inside which I am rendering a list containing some data, one below the other. I wanted every alternate `data` entry to have a different background color so I decided to make use of `nth-child` selctor in CSS.

### JSX Code to render a list of data

```js
<div className={styles.tableBody}>
  {tableRowsData.filter(filterMatch).map((row, rowIdx) => (
    <div
      key={rowIdx}
      className={styles.tableRow}
    >
      <div className={styles.value}>{row.url}</div>
      <div className={styles.value}>{row.startTime}</div>
      <div className={styles.value}>{row.endTime}</div>
      <div className={styles.value}>{row.status}</div>
      <div className={styles.value}>{row.score}</div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

## Outputs

### CSS Trial 1

When I use the following CSS, I get the background color is `white`.

```css
.tableBody:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--primary-red);
}
```

[image]

### CSS Trial 2

When I use the following CSS, I get the background color is `red`.

```css
.tableBody:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--primary-red);
}
```

[image]

### CSS Trial 3

When I use the following CSS, I get the background color is `red`. Instead of getting only the `2nd` card with a red background color.

```css
.tableBody:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: var(--primary-red);
}
```

[image]

### CSS Trial 4

When I use the following CSS, I get the background color is `red` for every alternate card and for every even card's odd child.

```css
.tableBody :nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--primary-red);
}
```

[image]

Could someone please help me understand this behavior and how to achieve what I wanted to?

### Desired Result

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I *think* you might want `.tableBody :nth-child(even)`

Comment: @Paulie_D I have updated my question to include the result for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tableBody:nth-child(odd)` matches `.tableBody` elements that are **themselves** the nth-child.

You only have one such element so it will always be the first (and odd) child.

If you want to select the elements with `styles.tableRow` inside it then you need to say so:

```
.tableBody > .tableRow:nth-child(odd)
```

(This assumes that the value of `styles.tableRow` is `'tableRow'`).